# Coding pmap in Solaris

Tags: c, solaris, pmap

I'm currently attempting to write my own program that mirrors the pmap command, specifically on Solaris 9. I'm  having trouble resolving the names and paths of the libraries. Output of the Solaris command looks something like this, from a bash shell:

```
bash-2.05# pmap $$
2427:   bash
00010000     496K r-x--  /usr/bin/bash
0009A000      80K rwx--  /usr/bin/bash
000AE000     120K rwx--    [ heap ]
FF100000     688K r-x--  /usr/lib/libc.so.1
FF1BC000      24K rwx--  /usr/lib/libc.so.1
FF1C2000       8K rwx--  /usr/lib/libc.so.1
FF200000     568K r-x--  /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1
FF29E000      32K rwx--  /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1
FF2A6000      32K rwx--  /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1
FF2F0000       8K rwx--    [ anon ]
FF300000      16K r-x--  /usr/lib/libmp.so.2
FF314000       8K rwx--  /usr/lib/libmp.so.2
FF320000       8K r-x--  /usr/platform/sun4u-us3/lib/libc_psr.so.1
FF330000      40K r-x--  /usr/lib/libsocket.so.1
FF34A000       8K rwx--  /usr/lib/libsocket.so.1
FF350000     168K r-x--  /usr/lib/libcurses.so.1
FF38A000      32K rwx--  /usr/lib/libcurses.so.1
FF392000       8K rwx--  /usr/lib/libcurses.so.1
FF3A0000       8K r-x--  /usr/lib/libdl.so.1
FF3B0000       8K rwx--    [ anon ]
FF3C0000     152K r-x--  /usr/lib/ld.so.1
FF3F6000       8K rwx--  /usr/lib/ld.so.1
FFBFC000      16K rw---    [ stack ]
 total      2536K
```

I can mostly duplicate the program's basic features by reading /proc/$$/map, but what remains is figuring out **how to resolve the library names**, shown on the right. /proc/$$/map only gives the names of the files in /proc/$$/object, which are just generic names. On Solaris 10 (a box I have), I seem to be able to use /proc/$$/path, which contains symbolic links, but the box I'm working on doesn't have these. Does anyone have any straightforward ideas on how to get these library names? When I truss the program, it seems to open up /proc/$$/as and look through the memory and somehow find them, but I haven't been able to figure out where it's looking or why quite yet.

Comment: If you google 'c pmap', you find one person's (old) re-engineering of pmap ( for solaris). It's not long. Maybe you can find there where you go wrong (if the code is still valid, considering its age).

Comment: The one I find is an implementation of pmap for Linux, which is unfortunately wholly different, since Linux /proc/$$/maps is a plaintext file that contains everything I need anyway. Was there something else you saw that I missed?

Comment: I checked again. You're right. I didn't read carefully. Apologies. I work in Linux unfortunately and so don't know how the two dialects' implementations differ.

Comment: I don't know on which level exactly it is implemented, but any luck with http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Main/get

Comment: Unfortunately the OpenSolaris version seems to work a little differently, at least from what I could tell. It tries to use the /proc/$$/path file, which isn't there on my Solaris 9, and otherwise defaults to device/inode names. Thanks again for looking around though! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Solaris implementation of `pmap` is actually available in source form via OpenSolaris,[`pmap.c`](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/cmd/ptools/pmap/pmap.c). But this is very complex stuff; the basics are simpler to achieve.

Solaris has *three* `/proc` handles for maps:

1. `/proc/<PID>/map` which contains [`struct prmap`](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/uts/common/sys/procfs.h#l323) data that reflects the "usual" working set size
2. `/proc/<PID>/rmap` which also contains `struct prmap` data but for the virtual set size (VSZ), i.e. reflecting mapped VA ranges even if the mapping is uncommitted.
3. `/proc/<PID>/xmap` which contains [`struct prxmap`](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/uts/common/sys/procfs.h#l337) data, which actually trawls the address space to identify memory-resident regions.

The `pmap` utility looks into these when you pass either no args (`map`), `-r` (`rmap`) or `-x` (`xmap`), but as you've found it does a lot more than simply opening/reading the map proc files. That's largely what makes the sourcecode hard to parse.

Nonetheless, you can construct a trivial Solaris `[rx]map` (use `struct prxmap` instead of `struct prmap` if you access `xmap` of course) parser via code like:

```
char mappath[MAXPATHLEN];
sprintf(mappath, "/proc/%d/map", getpid());
int fd = open(mappath, O_RDONLY);
size_t nread;
size_t mapsz = (1 << 20);                 /* start at 1MB */
struct prmap *cur*mapbuf = malloc(mapsz);

while ((nread = pread(fd, mapbuf, mapsz, 0)) == mapsz) {
    free(mapbuf);
    mapsz *= 2;
    mapbuf = malloc(mapsz);
}
for (cur = mapbuf; nread; cur++, nread -= sizeof(*mapbuf))
    prettyprint(cur);
free(mapbuf);
```

A few hints:

- don't try to `mmap()` the `map` file, that won't work (procfs doesn't allow it)
- don't try to sequentially read parts of it; the above (re-reading the whole from the *beginning* into a resized buffer) is *faster* than doing a contiguous sequence of `read()`. Always read from the beginning (use `pread` as in the example, or `lseek(..., 0, SEEK_SET)` before any `read`).

Enjoy experimenting !

**Edit:**

Since you've set your mind on finding the pathnames behind mappings, that's one of the really difficult tasks. `pmap` doesn't deal with that itself but uses the facilities of `libproc` to resolve these names, which, as you've found by `truss`, may trawl through the process address space to extract these, but also uses a few other techniques. It's essentially the "iter" functions in [`libproc/Psymtab.c`](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/lib/libproc/common/Psymtab.c) which do this. There's differences between Solaris 9 and later versions as well ... can't remember, too long ago ...

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, as well as the hint about it being faster to not do a bunch of sequential read() calls, since that's what I was doing!

Comment: For small maps (a few hundred entries) the overhead isn't measurable, but if you have hundreds of thousands of mappings, like a huge 64bit JVM instance, and possibly some dynamics in there as well, then it makes a hell of a difference.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer.

Comment: There's a way of getting pathnames but it works only for system libraries. You can look through prmap_t structures in /proc/<pid>/map file and get names of object files from /proc/<pid>/objects. Then it is possible to parse there objects as elf files and get library soname of each file which is the name of system .so file from /usr/lib or /lib. However this doesn't work for user's libs. Using libproc is the only way here, but it's interface is supposed to be closed, so you are to use nm utility and hope that the interface is similar to the one described in opensol.